# If any link elements contain the _ type then replace them with a script tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I know this is a really stupid idea but I need to know how to do this.

for every element like this:

```
<link _="/script.js"/>
```

replace it with this:

```
<script src="/script.js"></script>
```

Thanks For Your Help!

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript, use [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all `<link>` elements with the underscore `_` attribute, then loop over those results and get the value for the underscore `_` attribute. Create a new `<script>` element and set the `src` attribute of the new element to be the value retrieved from the `<link>` element. Then use [ChildNode.replaceWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith) to replace the old `<link>` element with the newly created `<script>` element.

```
var underscoreLinks = document.querySelectorAll("link[_]");
underscoreLinks.forEach(link => {
  var src = link.getAttribute("_");
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.setAttribute("src", src);
  link.replaceWith(script);
});
```